# Adding password strength indicator to RadTextBox truncates the width

Tags: html, asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010, telerik

I need to add the Telerik password strength checker thingy to a password field (a Telerik RadTextBox) but when I do it restricts the width to 60px, for no reason I can see.

The RadTextBox code looks like this:

```
<telerik:RadTextBox TextMode="Password" ID="rtb_NewPassword" 
    CssClass="RegisterTextbox" style="width:150px;" Runat="server" 
    LabelWidth="160px" Wrap="False">
</telerik:RadTextBox>
```

So when I add the strength checker it looks like this:

```
<telerik:RadTextBox TextMode="Password" ID="rtb_NewPassword" 
    CssClass="RegisterTextbox" style="width:150px;" Runat="server" 
    LabelWidth="160px" Wrap="False">
    <PasswordStrengthSettings ShowIndicator="true" PreferredPasswordLength="6"
        MinimumNumericCharacters="1" MinimumUpperCaseCharacters="1"
        MinimumLowerCaseCharacters="1" CalculationWeightings="50;15;15;20"
        IndicatorElementID="spn_StrengthIndicator"></PasswordStrengthSettings>
</telerik:RadTextBox>
```

The rendered HTML is as follows:

Without strength checker:

```
<span id="ExternalLogin_rtb_NewPassword_wrapper" class="riSingle RadInput
    RadInput_Glow" style="width:160px;">
    <input id="ExternalLogin_rtb_NewPassword" name="ExternalLogin$rtb_NewPassword"
        size="20" class="riTextBox riEnabled RegisterTextbox" type="password" />
    <input id="ExternalLogin_rtb_NewPassword_ClientState"
        name="ExternalLogin_rtb_NewPassword_ClientState" type="hidden" />
</span>
```

With strength checker: (note the span with the `60px` width)

```
<span id="ExternalLogin_rtb_NewPassword_wrapper" class="riSingle RadInput
    RadInput_Glow" style="width:160px;">
    <span class="riContentWrapper" style="width:60px;">
        <input id="ExternalLogin_rtb_NewPassword" name="ExternalLogin$rtb_NewPassword"
            size="20" class="riTextBox riEnabled RegisterTextbox" type="password" />
        <input id="ExternalLogin_rtb_NewPassword_ClientState"
            name="ExternalLogin_rtb_NewPassword_ClientState" type="hidden" />
    </span>
</span>
```

I can't see anywhere in the code or properties where this is defined. It just appears when the page is built.

Is there anyway to stop this happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try overriding using CSS

```
.riContentWrapper
{
width:100px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

I needed to change the `EnableSingleInputRendering` property to False.

Obvious really! (not)